# What is the best alternative of react-native-camera as it is now deprecated?

Tags: react-native, android-camera

I am working on a project that requires a custom camera view in react-native. And the best option I found is react-native-camera but lack of maintenance, it is deprecated now. So I searched a lot of libraries in react-native but did not found.

Comment: You can use [React Native Vision Camera](https://github.com/mrousavy/react-native-vision-camera) by [Marc Rousavy](https://github.com/mrousavy).

Answer (score 2):

You can go with
[**expo-camera**](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/camera/#usage)

works on both ios and android ✌️

Comment: Expo Camera is broken on IOS if the screen orientation is locked. Bug was reported years ago and it's not fixed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [react-native-vision-camera](https://github.com/mrousavy/react-native-vision-camera).

npm link > https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-vision-camera

Answer (score 2):

You can use react-native-vision-camera package

npm link : https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-vision-camera

github : https://github.com/mrousavy/react-native-vision-camera

docs: https://mrousavy.com/react-native-vision-camera/docs/guides/

installation:

```
npm i react-native-vision-camera
npx pod-install
```

Comment: Also if this anwser helped you please accept the answer by clicking the tick button :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use **react-native-cam-gallery** it have other useful functionality as well.

link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-cam-gallery

Comment: I will definitely try .

Answer (score 1):

There is a new cool library from Tesla: https://github.com/teslamotors/react-native-camera-kit